# Changing original pointer inside function

Tags: c, pointers

Say I have this code:

```
int * p = 7;
f(p);
printf(p);
```

write function f so that line 3 will print 0.

I wanted to just say p=0 but i dont think that the address inside the function will be the same as the one in wider scope, so just wanted a little help from someone who understands this well.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to change the address of p ? Or the value ?

Comment: @Pierre "write function f so that line 3 will print 0."

Comment: It's not clear what the reasoning behind asking this question is, so it's very hard to know what would constitute a good answer.

Comment: @glglgl The David Schawartz comment point why I posted those questions :)

Comment: Please be more concise with your questions. What are you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: Seems like a homework assignment to me...

Comment: ...by a teacher who doesn't know what's up as well.

Comment: The code is invalid no matter what function `f` you write. If it even compiles, it is impossible to tell what line 3 will print. My bet is on "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: " just wanted a little help from someone who understands this well" i dont think your question is helping any one to understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Corrections in your question**

1. `int *p` is a pointer to a integer, so you cant assign a number to it.

If I understand your question correct, You need the value of a pointer  to get changed within the function.

```
void function (int *p)
{
   int  i = 0;
   if(NULL == p)
   {
      printf("Input argument is NULL");
      return;
   }
   /* Change the value of the pointer */
   *p = i;
}
```

You can invoke this function as follows:

```
int main()
{
   int i = 3;
   function (&i);
   printf("i=%d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

**Code description:**

When you pass pointer to the function, actually a copy of pointer variable is created which in turn points to the same address as your original pointer. Though the pointer copy loses its scope after `function()` exits the value at the address you intended to modify is modified.

Answer (score -1):

Normally people don't want `7` as pointer value, so most probably the variable you want is `int num = 7;`

```
void f(int* pNum) {
  *pNum = 0;
}

int main() {
  int num = 7;
  f(&num);
  printf("%d",num);
  return 0;
}
```

but if you want to have the same syntax with your existing code, then

```
void f(int * p) {
  strcpy(p,"0");
}

int main() {
  int * p = malloc(2); // let's change to valid address
  f(p);
  printf(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why did I get down vote? comment please?

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't answer the posted question. Your second example is hilariously broken. Have you tried to compile and run it?

Comment: My snippets tried to guess what he actually wants in real life; it assumes OP is newbie and I did some error correction. In the first, normally people don't want `7` as pointer value, so most probably the variable he wants is `int num = 7;`. As for second answer, assuming he really wants to pass a pointer value to `f()` and then `printf()` using the value as format, then `f()` should just copy the string. Of course `7` as an address will cause problem, but when initialized properly, `f()` should do the job.